# Picked gallery Image path flutter

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I'm working on a app where I would like to get the local path of the selected/picked image from my mobile gallery instead of image_picker path. I have used image _picker to pick an image from the gallery. When I print the path of the selected image it showing something like this `/data/user/0/coffy.testapp/cache/image_picker5380473371212438250.jpg` instead I need a path of the image like `/data/emulated/downloads/021545.png` (The path I can see in my mobile when I click the image details of a particular image);

Answer (score 0):

You need to access local storage and select from there.

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files
https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider